# How to get update status of multiple Drupal sites

Tags: 7, security

I have several servers each with numerous Drupal sites on.
Not all of them are developed by me.

How would you keep on top of the sites to make sure they are all up to date security wise.
In an ideal world I would like them to report to a central location. From that one place I can be alerted.

Worse case I will write my own module to call a Web Service and send the status across. How ever if this has all ready been done will save some time.

Answer (score 2):

A search on drupal.org found [Drupal Remote Dashboard](https://drupal.org/project/drd)

If that module doesn't work for you, I would suggest a thorough search of drupal.org before jumping into creating your own module.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/) for this:

> Ægir is a mature set of contributed modules for Drupal that aims to
>   solve the problem of managing a large number of Drupal sites. It does
>   this by providing you with a simple Drupal based hosting front end for
>   your entire network of sites. To deploy a new site you simply have to
>   create a new Site node. To backup or upgrade sites, you simply manage
>   your site nodes as you would any other node.